# Assignment repositories

Tags: lesson-ideas, resource-request

Are there any assignment repositories that you use for assignment ideas? I am aware of the [Nifty Assignments](http://nifty.stanford.edu/) from Stanford and have used several. There are a lot of good fine grained problems on [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/), but I would not incorporate the work of a commercial group into an assignment.

Ideally, they would come with a write up and be licensed for general reuse with inclusion of a standard disclaimer, etc. Assignments with multiple parts so students get to live with their own code over a period of time would be great.

Answer (score 5):

Engage CS Edu (https://www.engage-csedu.org/) is another repository, which, like Nifty Assignments, is curated by peer review.

Comment: Thanks fior the link! Great stuff.

Answer (score 5):

At the beginning of every year I buy the UIL contest packet from the previous year from http://store.uiltexas.org/computer-science/ .  UIL is an organization that's over athletic and academic competitions in Texas.

Each packet is only $4 and contains around 50 programming problems and 200 multiple choice questions that were used in contests.

Sometimes I use [Riddler problems](https://fivethirtyeight.com/tag/the-riddler/) from FiveThirtyEight.com as a starting point for assignments. They're mathy, but with a little work can become programming problems.

Also math heavy, [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) has some good smallish type problems that can be solved with code.

Comment: Thanks for the links! Spent hours looking at the sites and lots of great ideas.